# To overload a method taking a base class and directing the extending classes method implementation

Tags: java, extends, overloading

The logic below is all three classes AppleLeaf, MangoLeaf and BananaLeaf extend
Leaf class. I have a method that takes a leaf object only. It should redirect me to the methods below based on the class type correctly. 
But I get error like, "The method handleLeaf(AppleLeaf) in the type main is not applicable for the arguments (Leaf)"

```
public void main(String args[]){

      for (Leaf leaf : leafList) {
      handleLeaf(leaf);     
   }
}

private void handleLeaf(AppleLeaf node) {   
    String colour = leaf.getColour();
    System.print.out(colour);
}

private void handleLeaf(MangoLeaf mLeaf) {
     Int veins = mLeaf.getVeinCount;
     System.print.out(veins);
}

 private void handleLeaf(BananaLeaf bLeaf) {    
    Boolean withered = bLeaf.getTexture();
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the subclass handle their own `handleLeaf` method instead of relying on the superclass to know all its child types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not quite how it works. You've defined three methods, none of which take `Leaf` as a parameter. Each one takes a subclass of `Leaf`, but we don't know which subclass of `Leaf` the given argument might be.

One workaround is to make a delegating method such as:

```
private void handleLeaf(Leaf leaf) {
    if(leaf instanceof AppleLeaf)
        handleLeaf((AppleLeaf)leaf);
    else if(leaf instanceof MangoLeaf)
        handleLeaf((MangoLeaf)leaf);
    ...//And so on
}
```

You may consider reworking your logic in general, however. Perhaps you can flip things around to define an abstract method in the `Leaf` class and have every leaf type handle itself in its own definition of the method.

Comment: is **handleLeaf((AppleLeaf) leaf);** is same as **handleLeaf(AppleLeaf leaf);** ? I mean do I have to write different implementation for taht method?

Comment: @yellow You're missing the point of Java inheritance. The superclass should not be responsible for identifying the subclass and dispatching to one of its own methods based on the subclass. Each subclass should have a handler function and the superclass should call that. The superclass should either implement the method and have it throw an exception, so if a subclass forgets to implement its handler it's an error, or should declare it as an abstract method (meaning you cannot instantiate an instance of the superclass).

Comment: @yellow And no, it's not the same, in that the latter won't compile. This code checks for the implementation of `Leaf` and casts each `Leaf` instance to the corresponding type. But this is a bad approach in almost all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upcast automatically like that. What you're looking for is dynamic method binding, which is not in Java. Java is a compiletime linked language, and hence, it will not compile/run.